# MySQL triggers pros & cons

Tags: mysql, triggers

In a nutshell, what are pros and cons of using triggers in MySQL? Yet I have not ever used neither triggers nor stored procedures in MySQL, so I'm used to solve any task I have using PHP for business logic and SQL for CRUD.
Now I've got a task to save table's history and thinking of usage of triggers for this purpose. So, the sub-question is: are triggers good for this particular task?

Comment: Have you thought about using the database logfiles to protocol changes inside your database?

Comment: nope. How this can be more simple to implement what I need comparing to triggers or php for business logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: (pros/cons of triggers vs implementing functionality in code, e.g. php)

Pros: easier to implement audit/history

Cons: harder to debug issues

Comment: this is the reason why I don't use stored procedures - I tried to get into this, but it's not a very pleasant process. If I need to modify the code, I have to delete the procedure and compile it again (I want to think there is a better way of doing this). and it's hard to debug (is there a better way than you just write a code, compile, if it does not work you fix it and compile again?).

Comment: P.S. no `alter trigger`, huh? http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/187387 Why MySQL sucks at business logic that much? (it's rhetorical question :) )

Comment: @Nemoden - I usually don't put any business logic in stored procs, I only use them to access data or insert/update it. I keep all business logic in the code.

Comment: And so do I, that's why I hesitate. Although, mysql triggers seems to be the most appropriate place for my task. To be clear: I wouldn't do that if we used a common interface for saving changes to the database (ORM/AR), so the code which can modify table records is spreaded among the codebase. That's actually the real issue, which is not solvable in the nearest future.